# Issue in nvidia-smi version and docker cuda ref in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, docker, aws

**The issue in Ubuntu 20.04:**

> 1. Issue in Cuda Version: ERR!

[image]

> 2. Issue in Cuda ref in Docker like:

- `cudaloader gstcudaloader.c:169:gst_cuda_load_library: Could not open library libcuda.so.1, libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Is your nvidia driver up to date?  I have 535.129.03 on my 22.04 system. How did you install CUDA? Many cuda installs will include an Nvidia video driver that is newer/older than the default system one from the standard repositories.

Comment: Issue resolved after a driver update for the Issue in Cuda Version: ERR!